# Offline Alternative to Overleaf with Fast Compile

Tags: compiling, offline

In several scenarios I want to use a Latex editor with fast and real-time compiling without the access to Internet. I've tried many softwares such as Tex studio; however, all of them take **several seconds** to compile the smallest possible change.

For example, this site (StackExchange) compiles a short passage of Latex formula within millisecond! This speed is definitely doable.

Comment: In (La)TeX the amount of change doesn't make a difference, as a small change at one place can change the entire document, so there is no real other choice than to compile everything anew. There are a few tricks to reduce compile time, but you'll never get a new compilation in milliseconds (provided your hardware is still affordable...).

Comment: You make it sound as if Overleaf is fast. In my experience, offline compilation is much faster than Overleaf. Personally, I don't like the auto-recompilation. In some cases, it will get into a tangle by recompiling too soon and require recompiling from scratch, which will take longer in almost all cases.

Comment: Kile has a live preview experimental feature, don't know how fast it is, not sure about several seconds - but I bet it depends on how big/heavy your tex is. Texstudio has a preview for sections of text/math that is pretty fast but does not include the entire document.

Comment: @cfr Oh, Overleaf is not that fast but for a small document and the draft mode, it takes around 1-2 seconds which is marginally acceptable. For the same small document of less than 30 pages, Tex studio took me around five seconds to compile.

Comment: @HighGPA I've always found local faster. Much faster usually.

Comment: @cfr Could you please share your software and settings?

Comment: @HighGPA I just use `pdflatex` mostly. Or `arara`, locally.

Comment: @cfr I find that this site (StackExchange) compiles a short passage of Latex formula within millisecond!

Comment: @HighGPA The difference is that StackExchange (actually the [MathJax library](https://www.mathjax.org/)) doesn't compile real LaTeX but a restricted variant which isn't as flexible as LaTeX. Especially they don't have features where every text can affect all the following text, therefore it is much easier to recompile a single formula etc.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I also observe that even this MathJax does not have the ability to recompile one formula without recompiling all formuli!